# constructing product measure, is this function well defined?

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading about product measure, and my book does this:

[image: pic]

A and B are measurable sets on a $\sigma$-algebra. Often I see that we have to prove that the function is well defined if we construct a new function. That is, if the argument can be represented in two different ways, the the function-value will be the same no matter which representation. Is this function well-defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\times B$ can be represented in only one way as a product of two sets (measurable or otherwise), unless $A = \varnothing$ or $B = \varnothing$. In that case, we have $\mu(A) = 0$ resp. $\nu(B) = 0$, and with the usual convention that $0\cdot x = 0 = x\cdot 0$ for all $x \in [0,\infty]$, that makes $\lambda$ well-defined.